# How to dynamically add radio button in popup menu?

Tags: java, android

```
  popup2.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.priorityAreazone,true,true);
  popup2.getMenu().add(R.id.priorityAreazone,(i),(i),zoneNames.get(i)).setCheckable(true);
```

I am trying to radio button to popup menu ,I am able to add checkbox but unable to add radio button how can  i do that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
public void showPopup(View v) {


    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this.getContext(), v, Gravity.RIGHT);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    //        popup.inflate(R.menu.hc_popup_check);
    //        popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item1).setChecked(true);
    int groupId = 1;
    popup.getMenu().add(groupId, 1, 1, "Share").setCheckable(true); 
    //.setChecked
    popup.getMenu().add(groupId, 2, 2, "Comment").setCheckable(true);
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: This is a solution only for chechboxes.